# extract data from a textfile in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I would like to extract the data in the grey areas from the textfile below and I would like to use matlab. It is not possible to count the number of lines in the heading because this changes each time I generate the textfile.

It should be something like this:

```
%open the file        
fin = fopen('panair.out');

buffer = fgetl(fin)    
if buffer(2:17)=='totals for column'
j=1
for i=1:3
    tmp=fgetl(fin)
end
    buffer=fgetl(fin);
    temp = strread(38:44);
    wingsection.area(j,k)= strread(temp, '%7.4f');
    temp = strread(38:44);
    wingsection.fx(j,k)= strread(temp, '%7.4f');
    temp = strread(38:44);
    wingsection.fy(j,k)= strread(temp, '%7.4f');
    temp = strread(38:44);
    wingsection.fz(j,k)= strread(temp, '%7.4f');
    temp = strread(38:44);
    wingsection.mx(j,k)= strread(temp, '%7.4f');
    temp = strread(38:44);
    wingsection.my(j,k)= strread(temp, '%7.4f');
    temp = strread(38:44);
    wingsection.mz(j,k)= strread(temp, '%7.4f');
    j=j+1;
  else
end

%close file
fclose(fin);
```

or maybe textscan is faster?

312   245     0.3625     0.4312    -0.0967     0.0862     0.1299    -0.7494     0.3114    -0.5276     0.0011     0.0011     0.0023
     0.4088     0.9159    -0.9661     0.0415     0.0431     0.9091    -0.9661     0.0415     0.1949    -0.7522    -0.7608    -0.7487
     0.3000     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736    -0.0431     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    -0.0050     0.5227    -0.5276     0.0000     1.3273     0.8525     0.8218     0.0000     0.1949    -0.7522    -0.7608    -0.7487

313   246     0.2859     0.4577    -0.0762     0.0604     0.1983    -0.8678     0.4854    -0.5023     0.0008     0.0012     0.0018
     0.4795     0.9985    -1.1277     0.2626     0.0302     0.9998    -1.1277     0.2626    -0.0605    -1.3393    -1.3402    -1.3003
     0.3000     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736    -0.0302     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    -0.0117     0.4906    -0.5023     0.0000     1.5297     0.8714     1.0139     0.0000    -0.0605    -1.3393    -1.3402    -1.3003

314   247     0.1572     0.4842    -0.0419     0.0224     0.4594    -1.1558     1.2420    -0.3774     0.0005     0.0012     0.0010
     0.8019     1.3070    -1.4401     1.1865     0.0112     1.3389    -1.4401     1.1865    -1.0491    -3.9991    -4.2495    -3.8789
     0.3000     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736    -0.0112     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
     0.0002     0.3776    -0.3774     0.0000     2.2966     0.9260     1.7576     0.0000    -1.0491    -3.9991    -4.2495    -3.8789

315   247     0.0724     0.4974    -0.0192    -0.0052     0.5621    -1.6209     1.7536    -0.3154     0.0005     0.0012     0.0010
     1.2086     1.4161    -1.8573     1.7344    -0.0026     1.4587    -1.8573     1.7344    -1.4755    -7.0415    -7.5368    -6.3779
     0.3000     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736     0.0026     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
     0.0636     0.3789    -0.3154     0.0000     2.9292     0.9254     2.4532     0.0000    -1.4755    -7.0415    -7.5368    -6.3779
1
0*b*for-mom-net#-  1
                                              force / moment data for network     1

```
 totals for column      1          area           fx            fy            fz            mx            my            mz


                                 0.03774      -0.08047       0.04658       0.22649       0.09508       0.03271       0.02334
                                 0.03774       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000
                                 0.03774      -0.08047       0.04658       0.22649       0.09508       0.03271       0.02334


 totals for column      2          area           fx            fy            fz            mx            my            mz


                                 0.03099       0.00955       0.01410       0.12176       0.05164       0.01277      -0.00630
                                 0.03099       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000
                                 0.03099       0.00955       0.01410       0.12176       0.05164       0.01277      -0.00630


 totals for column      3          area           fx            fy            fz            mx            my            mz


                                 0.03050       0.01257       0.00796       0.06866       0.03008       0.00319      -0.00604
                                 0.03050       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000
                                 0.03050       0.01257       0.00796       0.06866       0.03008       0.00319      -0.00604


 totals for column      4          area           fx            fy            fz            mx            my            mz


                                 0.03042       0.01116       0.00600       0.04510       0.02068      -0.00067      -0.00499
                                 0.03042       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000
                                 0.03042       0.01116       0.00600       0.04510       0.02068      -0.00067      -0.00499
```

312   245     0.3625     0.4312    -0.0967     0.0862     0.1299    -0.7494     0.3114    -0.5276     0.0011     0.0011     0.0023
     0.4088     0.9159    -0.9661     0.0415     0.0431     0.9091    -0.9661     0.0415     0.1949    -0.7522    -0.7608    -0.7487
     0.3000     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736    -0.0431     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    -0.0050     0.5227    -0.5276     0.0000     1.3273     0.8525     0.8218     0.0000     0.1949    -0.7522    -0.7608    -0.7487

313   246     0.2859     0.4577    -0.0762     0.0604     0.1983    -0.8678     0.4854    -0.5023     0.0008     0.0012     0.0018
     0.4795     0.9985    -1.1277     0.2626     0.0302     0.9998    -1.1277     0.2626    -0.0605    -1.3393    -1.3402    -1.3003
     0.3000     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736    -0.0302     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
    -0.0117     0.4906    -0.5023     0.0000     1.5297     0.8714     1.0139     0.0000    -0.0605    -1.3393    -1.3402    -1.3003

314   247     0.1572     0.4842    -0.0419     0.0224     0.4594    -1.1558     1.2420    -0.3774     0.0005     0.0012     0.0010
     0.8019     1.3070    -1.4401     1.1865     0.0112     1.3389    -1.4401     1.1865    -1.0491    -3.9991    -4.2495    -3.8789
     0.3000     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736    -0.0112     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
     0.0002     0.3776    -0.3774     0.0000     2.2966     0.9260     1.7576     0.0000    -1.0491    -3.9991    -4.2495    -3.8789

315   247     0.0724     0.4974    -0.0192    -0.0052     0.5621    -1.6209     1.7536    -0.3154     0.0005     0.0012     0.0010
     1.2086     1.4161    -1.8573     1.7344    -0.0026     1.4587    -1.8573     1.7344    -1.4755    -7.0415    -7.5368    -6.3779
     0.3000     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736     0.0026     0.9848     0.0000     0.1736     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
     0.0636     0.3789    -0.3154     0.0000     2.9292     0.9254     2.4532     0.0000    -1.4755    -7.0415    -7.5368    -6.3779
1
0*b*for-mom-net#-  1
                                              force / moment data for network     2

```
 totals for column      1          area           fx            fy            fz            mx            my            mz


                                 0.03774      -0.08047       0.04658       0.22649       0.09508       0.03271       0.02334
                                 0.03774       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000
                                 0.03774      -0.08047       0.04658       0.22649       0.09508       0.03271       0.02334


 totals for column      2          area           fx            fy            fz            mx            my            mz


                                 0.03099       0.00955       0.01410       0.12176       0.05164       0.01277      -0.00630
                                 0.03099       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000
                                 0.03099       0.00955       0.01410       0.12176       0.05164       0.01277      -0.00630


 totals for column      3          area           fx            fy            fz            mx            my            mz


                                 0.03050       0.01257       0.00796       0.06866       0.03008       0.00319      -0.00604
                                 0.03050       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000
                                 0.03050       0.01257       0.00796       0.06866       0.03008       0.00319      -0.00604


 totals for column      4          area           fx            fy            fz            mx            my            mz


                                 0.03042       0.01116       0.00600       0.04510       0.02068      -0.00067      -0.00499
                                 0.03042       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000       0.00000
                                 0.03042       0.01116       0.00600       0.04510       0.02068      -0.00067      -0.00499
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`fscanf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html). Particularly:

> `A = fscanf(fileID, format, sizeA)` reads `sizeA` elements into `A`, and positions the file pointer after the last element read. `sizeA` can be an integer, or can have the form `[m,n]`.

Comment: here is the file:[link](http://goo.gl/naJHA). I would like to extract the red values. for example, area = [0.03774 0.03099 0.03050 ...;0.03774 0.03099 0.03050] fx=[-0.08047  0.00955  0.01257 ...;-0.08047  0.00955  0.01257]